# What is RangeFinder("CTBookmark", "CTMarkupRange") in docx4j?

Tags: java, openxml, docx4j

In the BookmarksReplaceWithText.java sample for docx4j, I see the following line.  What does RangeFinder do exactly?  I could not find a clear description.

```
RangeFinder rt = new RangeFinder("CTBookmark", "CTMarkupRange");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the RangeFinder gathers all of the bookmark start and end points in the xml file. The RangeFinder needs to be put into a TraversalUtil along with the object you are searching in (can be the whole document or a paragraph or whatever):

```
RangeFinder rt = new RangeFinder("CTBookmark", "CTMarkupRange");
new TraversalUtil(paragraphs, rt);
```

Once this is done, you can call rt.getStarts() or rt.getEnds() to get a list of the start and end bookmark locations. What I mean by this is if you look at the XML file of a document you will find bookmark starts and bookmark ends for example:

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="BookmarkName"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>bookmark</w:t>
    </w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
```

With this you can replace the content as described in BookmarksReplaceWithText.java or any number of other things.

Answer (score 0):

See [RangeFinder.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/finders/RangeFinder.java)

It gives you a list of the bookmark start and end objects.